# Typical problem in boom headset

Tags: comfort, headphones

I have bought a boom headset, I used it for an hour and obviously my ears started to heat up and end up with a lot of sweat. **How to avoid these heating up?**

Comment: Ideal mediocre boom headset will not heat this much in an hour. Can you check if it is product defect. Better to replace if it is so.

Comment: What is a 'boom headset'? How is it different from a normal headset? And what sort of headset are you using anyway? Over-ear? In-ear? Are you ears getting hot because the headset is getting hot, or due to lack of proper ventilation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I stop my ears from getting sweaty/greasy while wearing large headphones?](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/1735/how-do-i-stop-my-ears-from-getting-sweaty-greasy-while-wearing-large-headphones)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use your over-the-ear boom headset only on a well air conditioned room. For rest of the environment a in-the-ear headset is recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone at my work has headphones like this.  They have a simple solution: **wear them one ear at a time**, and switch ears every 20-30 minutes.  I'd also recommend listening to it with both ears until you just start to get uncomfortable, then go one ear at a time until you cool down.  I know it's probably not exactly what you're looking for, but it works pretty well.